# shell script to search files under multiple directories and renaming them

Tags: linux

I have 3 main directories, each main directories have multiple sub-folders and files in the sub-folders with different names and extensions.

I would like to have a script which does find in all the 3 main directories and add suffix `_create` to all the files but not directories.  Files should remain in the sub-folders as is but with `_create` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You could start at the top level containing the 3 main directories, and if those are the only directories do

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} {}_create \;
```

Comment: @ravi if that worked you should probably accept the answer for when people search in the future, and I'd appreciate an upvote as well if you found it useful.